# Fastest way to create array from string

Tags: php

Hy,

I'm creating a script to load a binary file into an array then parse the array myself (creating another array with decoded binary data : IA5String, Int, String, (basicaly ASN.1) etc and then create a .csv)

The problem that slows my script down is loading the hex values into an array and i'm using this method :

```
$hex = explode(" ",rtrim(chunk_split(bin2hex(file_get_contents($filename)),2,' ')));
```

The thing is that `explode()` function is taking a lot of time and resources and I was wondering if there is another faster or maybe simpler solution to save some running time.

Thanks

Comment: How about reading the file in smaller chunks and converting them to hex and further as you go? You will need less memory that way.

Comment: yes but the values there are TLV - Tag Length Value so I cannot load them in chunks because I need to load exactly as the length of that specific tag ... Like 0D 12 XX XX XX XX - 0D - tag, 12 - length (hex to dec) , XX XX XX - content

Comment: The for every TLV you can read tag, length and then as many bytes ss length says, convert that,  then repeat.

Answer (score 0):

str_split is another function to convert string to array.